# LINQ Query not hitting the database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm having an issue with a really simple password hash retrieval LINQ query. The problem is if the user logs out, then tries to log back it, it just uses the cached values of the query without querying the database again. The query in question is the following:

```
using (var db = new DataModel.DatabaseContext())
{
    return (from emp in db.Employees where emp.Username == username select emp.Password).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

But when I break, it seems that EF **IS** executing a reader on a separate thread! Then why do I think it isn't really querying the database? Well the execution time is just too short. It messes up my `async` methods, it basically doesn't leave enough time for a `MessageBox` to be shown (works properly when I call the method for the first time). Maybe the database itself has some transient options set up?

**EDIT**: I thought I found out what the problem is but this is just unreal. It executes the query on a remote server faster than a ping request. <0.001s I'm stumped

Comment: Your application relies on slowness of fetching data from database?

Comment: "uses the cached values of the query" - I don't think EF has caching for data, only for query structure and metadata. Do you actually see an old value being used, or just rely on the timing?

Comment: Instead of guessing based on some async timing, just have the sql profiler running in the background and you will clearly see if it hits the db or not. My guess is it does, it just does it faster as the query plan is already cached by the ef.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I haven't thought about this. The data itself isn't cached, but the query plan IS. The flaw is in my application design.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the first time you create a `DbContext` in your AppDomain (maybe first call to `new YourDbContext()` in your application) there is going a lot of initialization and configuration under the hood so it takes some time the first time, but after that (while application is running) the process speeds up so you can't feel it.

Comment: The `DatabaseContext` is wrapped in a `using` block. I'm using one context per request.

Comment: First time you create it in an AppDomain.